# get parent of grand children tree stored in database

Tags: mysql, sql, tree

I stored a tree in a table. The tree have the structure:

```
Category > Sub category > sub sub category
```

The parent here is the one with parent_id of 0.
I need to get the cat_id of any category with parent id = 0

```
cat_id | parent_id | name
-------------------------
1      |    0      | a
2      |    0      | b
3      |    1      | c
4      |    2      | d
5      |    3      | e
6      |    4      | f
```

so for the cat_id of 6, the top cat_id of whci the parent_id = 0

The only way is to select three sql statement like these

```
Select parent_id where cat_id  =  6  // the answer is 4
Select parent_id where cat_id  =  4  // the answer is 2
Select parent_id where cat_id  =  2  // the answer is 0
```

i need to find a more effective way to find the parent without three sql statement

Comment: It's not clear what is your question, dies your query not work / do you want to find a more effective one...? I think for the table structure you have there isn't a better query you may consider to choose a structure more suitable for storing hierarchical data.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I need to find a more effective way to select, if possible one statement

Comment: If you know the maximum depth of your tree, you can use a series of self joins, otherwise, this requires a recursive query, which is not (to my knowledge) supported by MySQL.  See: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46127/recursive-self-joins for possible other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - this will trace up the parents one by one till it gets to the topmost one and it will return that.

```
select @pv from
(select @pv:=t.parent_id
from (select * from cat order by cat_id desc) t
join (select @pv := 7) tmp
where t.cat_id = @pv) a limit 1;
```

Replace 7 by 6 or whichever leaf you want. If that leaf doesn't exist, no rows are returned.

Comment: by the way you are still using three sql statements. but just all in one

Comment: those are not 3 separate queries. it doesn't matter how much deep you go into, this statement would work. So if you had 9 with parent_id 6, the above query would still work. SQL Fiddle if you want to play around - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c083f/2

Answer (score -1):

1. Your question is not clear enough to understand what do yo want.
2. You my also  want to list out a categories table  and the output